# How to assign unique ID to guest user through out the session

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and working on eCommerce project and I need to add product into cart as a guest user currently I am checking the IP and User-Agent and encode both with md5 and cosider this unique id of current guest user there is any other better way to for a guest user

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP `session_id` for this: https://www.php.net/session_id

A drawback is that this `session_id` is only considering the technical session, so if a user is visiting your eCommerce application again the ID might change (but the IP and user agent might not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UUID` for that purpose. You can generate an almost a unique ID using this package https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid.
Read about the UUID here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Use UUID and store in cookie of client